# Accessing HTML using jQuery within LeafletJS popup.

Tags: leaflet, html, jquery

So I want to add some HTML code to a Leaflet popup, but I also want to be able to to perform some jQuery functions when this HTML is clicked, like so:

```
.bindPopup( "<button id='clickHere'> <strong> stuff </strong> </button>" ))
```

But I'm unable to access this using jQuery selectors, because it's inside  tags.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a simple action, you can just use the `onclick` attribute, like this:

```
.bindPopup( "<button id='clickHere' onclick='alert(...)'> <strong> stuff </strong> </button>" ))
```

An other, slightly more difficult way to do this would be to catch the `popupopen` event and bind an action to the `onclick` event inside it:

```js
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
  var marker = e.popup._source; # Source popup
  $('#clickHere').click(function() { 
    ... 
  });
});
```

Comment: Great thanks, that is perfect. One more quick question, It's possible to make onclick calls to an external JS file, right?

Comment: If the JS file is correctly loaded with the HTML file, yes, absolutely. You should however ensure that your external file is loaded after the main document (this often leads to trouble).